# Swift compiler error when adding ObjC .h to bridging header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am getting a weird error on my application when trying to add an ObjC .h file to the bridging header. In particular, when I try to add the header for `STXFeedPhotoCell.h`, the project fails to compile with the following error (this error is displayed in `STXFeedPhotoCell.h`. Here is my bridging header:

```
#import "NetworkHelper.h"
#import "ArtistModel.h"
#import "UIImageView+Masking.h"
#import "CommentModel.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "STXFeedPhotoCell.h"
```

And here is the error thrown:

```
/pathToProject/Helden der Volksmusik/STXDynamicTableView/Cells/STXFeedPhotoCell.h:12:9: 'NSDate+DateTools.h' file not found
```

Indeed, `STXFeedPhotoCell.h`, has an `import` statement for file `NSDate+DateTools.h`.

If I remove line `#import "STXFeedPhotoCell.h"` from the bridging header, then everything compiles fine.

Would appreciate any pointers on why the compiler is getting this error, or if there is a problem in the way these dependencies are being managed for swift (I am using cocoa pods with frameworks enabled).

Comment: `NSDate+DateTools.h` is added into your project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni: what do you mean by "added into your project", exactly? It is added via podfile, if that's what you mean.

Comment: As your error says `'NSDate+DateTools.h' file not found` means it is not in your project.

Answer (score 0):

To import DateTools and use it in Swift, you have to add this to your bridging file:

```
#import "DateTools/NSDate+DateTools.h"
```